# GitLab CI runner can't connect to tcp://localhost:2375 in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I followed this doc to install Gitlab on GKE :
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_chart.html

My installation's parameters are :

```
helm upgrade --install gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
  --timeout 600 \
  --set global.hosts.domain=***** \
  --set global.hosts.externalIP=***** \
  --set certmanager-issuer.email=***** \
  --set gitlab.migrations.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-rails-ce \
  --set gitlab.sidekiq.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-sidekiq-ce \
  --set gitlab.unicorn.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-unicorn-ce \
  --set gitlab.unicorn.workhorse.image=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-workhorse-ce \
  --set gitlab.task-runner.image.repository=registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitlab-task-runner-ce \
  --set gitlab.gitlab-runner.runners.privileged=true \
  --set gitlab.gitlab-runner.runners.cache_dir="cache"
```

Then I created my .gitlab-ci.yaml :

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375

stages:
  - package

package:
  stage: package
  before_script:
    - echo "${GKE_JSON_AUTH}" > gke-project-auth.json || exit 1
    - cat gke-project-auth.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io || exit 1
  script:
    - docker info
```

I have read many threads, all get the solution in `DOCKER_HOST` and `privileged`parameter, but I've always got this error :

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the
>   docker daemon running?

I also tried to put in a values.yaml file :

```
runners:
  privileged: true
```

and exectue this command :

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values gitlab gitlab/gitlab -f values.yaml
```

But without unsuccessfully...

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake. The "Installation command line options" we can see here :
https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab/blob/master/doc/installation/command-line-options.md says the `privileged` parameter is `gitlab-runner.runners.privileged` not `gitlab.gitlab-runner.runners.privileged` (and `cache_dir` doesn't exist).
So now it's OK with :

```
--set gitlab-runner.runners.privileged=true
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still have the same problem

Comment: @NoahMartin What is your complete command which doesn't work?

Comment: this was my problem: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/64959
It's a fresh issue from gitlab.

Comment: As written in gitlab-ci.yaml file in my first message, the DOCKER_HOST must be `tcp://localhost:2375` and not `tcp://docker:2375` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried that also but didn't work. The link above explains my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, according to [this](https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab/issues/478#note_195998015), this issue is more recently related to docker's update of its image `docker:dind` which use the last version of docker server which is not listening anymore at `2375` but at `2376`.

So I updated my `.gitlab-ci.yml` as suggested in that entry and it worked for me:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:18.09-dind

...
```

[UPDATE]

This was a temporary workaround. The `docker:stable` and `docker:stable-dind` images are now fixed.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this update... and what do you set in DOCKER_HOST so far?

Comment: OK, I set `tcp://localhost:2375` back instead of `2376` and it's working again... Bah

Comment: Hi, I tried that (using port 2376) in Dind on Kubernetes but I found out that 2376 expects TLS. I had to go back to old v18 version to have 2375 back. Can I enable non TLS port 2375 in new versions of Dind images? thanks.

Comment: @icordoba Hi, I must say that this was a temporary fix. The `docker:stable` and `docker:stable-dind` images don't have this issue any more. Regarding what you've asked you might find an answer for that [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-disabled).

Comment: thanks @LeandroOrdonez I tried last docker:stable-dind but it only listens to port 2376 with TLS, not 2375. Is it possible to configure it to listen to 2375 too?

Answer (score 0):

This solution using `docker:18.09` and `docker:18.09-dind` images works.

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build_image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:18.09
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  services:
    - docker:18.09-dind
```

More discussion on this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4501

Answer (score 0):

Your root cause is probably linked to security update of ***dind*** : TLS certificates are required or must be explicitly disabled.
The elegant and reliable solution is here : https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/

Answer (score -1):

The Docker-in-Docker service will be named after its image name: docker. You should set `DOCKER_HOST` to `tcp://docker:2375`.

Comment: I've already tried this solution and I had this message : `error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host`

Comment: When using docker in docker the docs say to use localhost - but it doesn't work neither does above answer